# An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) IPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
{
    HttpCookie authoCookies = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authoCookies != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authoCookies.Value);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        User1 user = js.Deserialize<User1>(ticket.UserData);
        MyIdentity myIdentity = new MyIdentity(user);
        MyPrincipal myPrincipal = new MyPrincipal(myIdentity);
        HttpContext.Current.User = myPrincipal;  //here
    }
}
```

Error is in the very last line...

Here is MyPrincipal class.

```
public class MyPrincipal
{
    private readonly MyIdentity MyIdentity;
    public MyPrincipal(MyIdentity _myIdentity)
    {
        MyIdentity = _myIdentity;
    }
    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return MyIdentity; }
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return Roles.IsUserInRole(role);
    }
}
```

What to do? I am following this tutorial

http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/06/part4-how-to-implement-custom-forms-authentication-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `MyPrincipal` misses to declare the implemented interface `IPricipal`:

```
public class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal
{ //...
```

There is no duck typing in C#.